# Is it a good practice to return HTML from Php/Mysql function?

Tags: php, mysql, templates, coding-style

For example have a look at the below code, It return links based on status it get from database.

```
function favourite_store_link ($store_id, $user_id)
    {
        (string) $display_output = null;

        if ($user_id)
        {

            $is_favourite = $this->count_rows('favourite_stores', "WHERE store_id='" . $store_id . "' AND user_id='" . $user_id . "'");

            $fav_store = ($is_favourite) ? 'remove' : 'add';
            $fav_store_msg = ($is_favourite) ? MSG_ADD_TO_FAVOURITE_STORES : MSG_REMOVE_FROM_FAVOURITE_STORES;
            $display_output = ' [ <a href="' . process_link('shop', array('user_id' => $store_id, 'fav_store' => $fav_store)) . '">' . $fav_store_msg . '</a> ]';
        }

        return $display_output;
    }
```

I want to ask if it is OK to do so or I must return the state of affairs and let template handle the rest.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to

Comment: It's ok, check ob_start() and other related functions if you want to display a full page in one time instead of all the parts one by one along the code execution (display optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much better to split logic and view to different parts of code.
If you just return data from your function you will have flexibility to use this function in other places, different views etc.

Dividing responsibilities is the one of main principles of good maintainable code. You can read more about it [here](https://sites.google.com/site/dhntclub/thiet-ke-web-site/trao-doi/the-m-in-mvc-why-models-are-misunderstood-and-unappreciated)

Comment: Thanks. The blog also have very useful information.